# I am gettingt this error in flutter firebase_auth, and I can't find any resource online.[firebase_auth/resolve-signin-failed]

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I am receiving an error "firebase_auth/resolve-signin-failed" and the message is "The SMS verification code used to create the phone auth credential is invalid. Please resend the verification code SMS and be sure to use the verification code provided by the user." My code to call login works fine when registering the user.

Here's my code for calling login:

```dart
Future<bool> loginuser() async {
  Completer<bool> completer = Completer<bool>();
  final smsCode = _otpController.text;

  if (smsCode.length < 6) {
    errorDialog("Invalid SMS code, new code will be sent to you.");
  }

  print("SMS CODE $smsCode");
  final PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
      verificationId: verificationId, smsCode: smsCode);

  try {
    await widget.resolver!.resolveSignIn(
      PhoneMultiFactorGenerator.getAssertion(
        credential,
      ),
    );
  } on NoSuchMethodError catch (e) {
    errorDialog("Server Error, try logging in again.");
    completer.complete(false);
  } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
    print(e);
    if (e.message ==
        "The verification ID used to create the phone auth credential is invalid.") {
      errorDialog("Invalid OTP. New OTP is sent");
      print(verificationId);
      await resendSmsLogin();
      print(verificationId);
    } else if (e.code == "too-many-requests") {
      errorDialog("You have made too many requests, try again later!");
    } else if (e.code == "invalid-verification-id") {
      errorDialog("New Verification Code has been sent to you");
      resendSmsLogin();
      setState(() {
        seconds = 120;
      });
    } else if (e.code == "resolve-signin-failed") {
      if (e.message == "MFA_ENROLLMENT_NOT_FOUND") {}
      errorDialog("Invalid OTP.");
      // resendSmsLogin();
      setState(() {
        seconds = 120;
      });
    } else {
      errorDialog("Contact: info@somerandomemail.com");
    }

    completer.complete(false);
  } on Exception catch (e) {
    errorDialog("Server Error, try logging in again.");
    completer.complete(false);
  }

  return await completer.future;
}
```

My Dependencies:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  google_nav_bar: ^5.0.6
  intl: ^0.17.0
  google_fonts: ^4.0.4
  firebase_core: ^2.14.0
  firebase_auth: ^4.6.3
  flutter_riverpod: ^2.3.6
  riverpod_annotation: ^2.1.1
  flutter_hooks: ^0.18.0
  hooks_riverpod: ^2.3.6
```

This is the error I get.

> flutter: [firebase_auth/resolve-signin-failed] The SMS verification code used to create the phone auth credential is invalid. Please resend the verification code SMS and be sure to use the verification code provided by the user.

I have checked that the verificationId is correct. Also, I have checked the value of smsCode. I think the resolver is being passed correctly since it passes the null assertion, and also the fact that I can resend the OTP and the verificationId change can be seen.